How to increase thumb size of a Switch in Flutter
I want the following thumb size to match as per the given image.
inactive switch sample
active switch sample
But the switch looks like this in active and inactive mode.
this how my code makes it look
Here's the code:
Switch(
        value: value,
        onChanged: (){},
        trackOutlineWidth: 0,
        trackOutlineColor: value
            ? blue
            : grey,
        activeTrackColor: blue,
        inactiveThumbColor: white,
        inactiveTrackColor: grey,
      ),

What should I add/modify to make it match the design?

I had to solve this same problem. The Flutter folks didn't think we would want to deviate from the Material Design guidelines, I suppose. :) Anyway, here's how I did it:
thumbIcon: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Icon>(
  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states
        .containsAll([MaterialState.disabled, MaterialState.selected])) {
      return const Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.red);
    }

    if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
      return const Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.blue);
    }

    if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
      return const Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.green);
    }

    return const Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.yellow);
  },
),


Not sure if there is a better way because this feels a bit like a work around but giving it this thumbIcon seems to work:
thumbIcon: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Icon(null)),


Thank you, but this doesn't work. Also we have to use
thumbIcon: MaterialStateProperty.all(null),

@AnanyaPathak it won't work with thumbIcon: MaterialStateProperty.all(null), only with thumbIcon: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Icon(null)), 

Please use this code:
Transform.scale(
 scaleX: 0.9,
 scaleY: 0.9,
 child: Switch(
    value: value,
    onChanged: (){},
    trackOutlineColor: value
        ? blue
        : grey,
    activeTrackColor: blue,
    inactiveThumbColor: white,
    inactiveTrackColor: grey,
  ),

